# Dual Network Gateway on CentOS 6.7

Tags: centos, networking, route, asterisk, sip

I have dual NIC machine running CentOS 6.7 and asterisk. First NIC is for LAN & Internet connectivity and second is for trunk provider's connectivity. Both of these have gateways configured. I don't seem to be able to access the Internet as the traffic is routed thru the Second NIC's gateway, also the second NIC is taken as default route by the kernel. I do not understand how default gateway is assigned in this case and what correction should I do.

Eth0 Config:

```
DEVICE=eth0
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=192.168.0.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.0.100
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=8.8.4.4
```

Eth1 Config:

```
DEVICE=eth1
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=10.165.11.139
NETMASK=255.255.255.248
GATEWAY=10.165.11.137
```

Ping Internet

```
ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.165.11.137 icmp_seq=1 Destination Net Unreachable
```

Ping SIP Trunk

```
ping 10.232.130.170
PING 10.232.130.170 (10.232.130.170) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.232.130.170 (10.232.130.170): icmp_seq=1 ttl=253 time=3.14 ms
```

Routing Table

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.165.11.136   *               255.255.255.248 U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1003   0        0 eth1
default         10.165.11.137   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the `eth1` config file and comment out/delete the `gateway` line and restart `network` service as follows:

```
service network restart
```

Now you should see `192.168.0.100` as your default router and everything should be working as expected.

By default, all the traffic related with the subnet of the `eth1` interface, will go through that interface because the kernel will create that entry.

It's good to mention that all the traffic (except 10.165.11.136/255.255.255.248), will go through your default gateway, but in case you want to route some specific traffic through `eth1` interface you can do as follows:

Runtime:

```
ip route add X.X.X.X/32 via 10.165.11.137 dev eth1
```

Permanent:

1. Create the file `/etc/sysconfig/network-script/route-eth1`
2. Add a line like this

   > X.X.X.X/32 via 10.165.11.137
3. Restart network service to apply

   > service network restart

Comment: I tried removed gateway from eth1, I can ping 10.165.11.137 (gateway), but 10.232.130.170 (remote host) is surprisingly not reachable.  ip route add X.X.X.X/32 via 10.165.11.137 dev eth1, how do I make this generic for all 255 hosts of 10.232.130.X subnet?

Comment: @user1263746 The IP 10.232.130.170 is out the subnet of eth1 interface. You should add a route. Something like this: ip route add 10.232.130.0/24 via 10.165.11.137 dev eth1.